# Doubt about a metric space analysis task

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

We have $X=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le9\right\}$, with the standard $d$ euclidean metric.
Let $B_2 = X$, and we have:

$$B_1=B_2\cap\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:(x-2)^2+y^2\le16\right\}$$

Prove, that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are closed balls, and for them, $B_1 \subset B_2$ stands, while $r_1 > r_2$ ($r$ stands for radius)!

I just don't understand how $r_1>r_2$ could stand, if $B_1$ is actually smaller than $B_2$.

Here is what I made about this task:

[image]

Comment: I think you have misunderstanding here, or I am not understanding what you are saying. Your set $B_1$ is not a ball(it is intersection part of two circles you drew), so talking about radius of it does not make sense. MY guess is that $r_1,r_2$ refer to radius of $X$ and the bigger ball, not $B_1$. Note also that $B_1 \subset B_2$ is obvious from the definition... So only thing you really need to prove is that closed balls are closed, and then their intersection $B_1$ is then clearly closed.

Comment: $B_1$ is the closed ball, in $X$, centered at $(2,0)$ of radius $4$. It's the oval shaped area in your smaller circle. (The smaller circle is $X$; everything lives there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's establish the definition of a closed ball, relative to some metric space $X$. A subset $B$ of $X$ is a closed ball in $X$ iff there exists $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ such that $B = \{ y \in X | d(x,y) \le r \}$, where $d$ is the metric on $X$ ($r$ and $x$ are called the radius and center of $B$, respectively). Note that the closure of an open ball is not necessarily equal to the closed ball of the same center and radius.

For the problem, our metric space is $X = B_2$, with the usual euclidean metric $d$. Our goal is to show that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are closed balls in $X$. $B_2$ is a closed ball in $X$ (it's just $X$ itself) with center at $(0,0)$ and radius $3$ (recall that $d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$, where $x = (x_1,x_2)$, $y = (y_1,y_2)$). Now how to show that $B_1$ is a closed ball relative to our space $X$? Well, just choose $r=4$, and center $x = (2,0)$ and note that $\{y \in X|d(x,y) \le 4\}$ is the same as the set $B_1$! Thus, $B_1$ is a closed ball in $X = B_2$. This was a matter of some definition pushing ^-^.

Also, see $r_1 = 4 > 3 = r_2$, which is what you wanted.